# Why is detailTextLabel not visible?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cell, detailtextlabel

`detailTextLabel` is not visible (code below). Can you tell me why?

```
 // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...

NSString *cellValue = [myListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Hello "; // This is not visible
cell.image = [myListArrayImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The `detailTextLabel` is not displayed for `cells` with the `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` style.  `init` the `UITableViewCell` with `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` instead and you should see your `detailTextLabel`.

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 32):

Or if you are using Interface Builder, change the `Style` cell property to `Subtitle`. :)

[image: Style cell property in Interface Builder.]

Comment: what's the equivalent of the method if doing it programatically?

Comment: Thanks guys, I am on it

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve it programmatically:

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "identifier")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used this and it worked for me:

```
// programming mark ----- ----- ---- ----- ----- ---- ----- ----- ----

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let CellIdentifier: String = "CellIdentifier"

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
    }

    cell!.textLabel!.text = "Title"
    cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = "Value"

    return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

> You can enable this inside cellForRowAt method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = qus[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ans[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: May be a little introduction to what you have done differently might help others.

Comment: I am confused, why use dequeueReusableCell when you're redeclaring the cell on the next line?

Comment: This is NOT good, as you do not reuse the actual reusable cell. You create a new one. This can lead to performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to mention that the wording in the UITableViewCell class reference can be a little bit confusing on this issue:

(After describing each cell type)

"**Discussion**
In all these cell styles, the larger of the text labels is accessed via the textLabel property and the smaller via the detailTextLabel property."

It might seem that it's saying *all* of the cell types include a detailTextLabel, but if you carefully read through them it's only the default type that does **not** have a detailTextLabel.